# C++: "Short Circuit" in the if statement not working and giving error

Tags: c++

I'm just starting out with c++ and wrote a very basic program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0, limit = 10;

    if ((count == 0) && (limit < 20))
     cout << "expr1 ran well" << endl;
    
    if (count == 0 && limit < 20)
     cout << "expr2 ran well" << endl;

    if ((limit > 20) || (count < 5))
     cout << "expr3 ran well" << endl;

    if (!(count == 12))
     cout << "expr4 ran well" << endl;
    
    if ((count == 1) && (x < y))
     cout << "expr5 ran well" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I compile this using g++, I'm getting an error

```
ste_1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ste_1.cpp:24:23: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
   24 |  if ((count == 1) && (x < y))
      |                       ^
ste_1.cpp:24:27: error: ‘y’ was not declared in this scope
   24 |  if ((count == 1) && (x < y))
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. The last `if` statement should demonstrate Short-Circuting and run normally but instead it's executing the 2nd statement when there's no need to (1st is false so `&&` should give false as output straightaway)

Comment: "Short circuit" means it will not evaluate right part in certain conditions, it does not mean it will compile any invalid random code you dump there.

Comment: It might not actually do the comparison at run time, but the expression still needs to be valid... so the variables have to be declared first.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with short-circuiting: you haven't declared `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks. I declared the variables and now it's working as expected.

Comment: "*it's executing the 2nd statement*" No. It's not executing anything, because you can't execute code that failed to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with short circuit. You used the following comparison `x < y`, but you never defined nor declared `x` and `y`.

if they are variable then define them beforehand like:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
```

if they are constants then define them beforehand like:

```
const int x = 5;
const int y = 6;
```

or if they are supposed to be macro define them before using them like:

```
#define x 7
#define y 8
```

Comment: Unrelated: In modern C++ prefer `constexpr int x = 7;` to `#define x 7`. With a `constexpr` variable you'll get the same compile time resolution of `x` that you'd get with the macro, but with the added advantages of type checking and not finding all of the other places in you program you use the token `x` replaced with `7` not matter how stupid and illogical the substitution may be.

Comment: @user4581301 `const int` and `constexpr int` are exactly the same. `enum{x=7};` is, however, interesting as it's literally a named value you can't ODR use.

Answer (score 1):

1. you should know that your code should be "build", then "link", and then can "execute".
2. Short circuit works at run-time, aka the "execute", but now what you faced is compile-time issue, aka the "build" time issue.

Answer (score 0):

That the code will never be executed doesn't free you from the requirement to write code that would be valid if it were.

You're in Churchill territory here, the compiler is telling you "this is the sort of nonsense up with which I shall not put!".  There's a pretty strong argument to be made that this is a safety feature: clearly you didn't intend to write gibberish, so that has to be a mistake worth correcting.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not a scripting language. First, you link and compile your source code (`.cpp`) and if it is successful you'll get an executable that you can run.

[image: imag link]

In the linking step, multiple codes or libraries that you've included will be linked together to make a single source code.
In compiling, the compiler does lexical analysis, syntax analysis, semantic analysis, etc before code generation. This where it acknowledges the undefined variables and you got that error.

A short circuit that you mention will happen at execution time, which is after compilation.